# Can we restrict file sharing of document in salesforce to just view?

Tags: administration

I am looking to upload a file say a pdf or .doc file into salesforce and i want this file only to  be viewed. I dont want any users to download it.

Looking at the documentation i can see that [image]

Is there a way to restrict download?

Comment: In what way do you mean edit? Edit the doc itself? or the object that the doc is attached to?  - On computers - once you see the object - 99.99% you can modify it in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way that I know of to restrict files in this way is to create a content delivery that doesn't allow downloading and share the link with the users.  Effectively the users have no access to the document inside Salesforce.  The problem with this is that you can't do this in an automated fashion, so its not a particularly scalable solution.